# ASP.NET c# print out html content

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net

I am learning .NET for a college project, having an already solid knowledge of PHP. I want to find out how to print out html content in .NET like I would do in PHP.

PHP example:

```
<?php
    $array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
    for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {

       echo "<p id=\"$i\">This is paragraph $i.</p>"; 

    }
?>
```

This is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve and understand. How would I do the above in ASP.NET?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this on your page

```
  <%   
  var array = new string[]{"foo", "bar", "hello", "world"};
  Response.ContentType = "text/html";
  for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
  {
  Response.Write(string.Format("<p id=\"{0}\">This is paragraph {0}.</p>",i)); 
  }
  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the below:

```
<%
   var array = new string[]{"foo", "bar", "hello", "world"};
   Response.ContentType = "text/html";
   for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
      Response.Write(string.Format("<p id=\"{0}\">This is paragraph {0}.</p>",i)); 
   }
%>
```

Comment: Do I put this code inside a Panel? Or where does it go?